# BackboneJS View - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following Backbone View with a render function that looks like the following:

```
render: function () {
this.emptyContent();
    if (this.model.get('ChatsInQueue') == -1) {
        this.model.set('ChatsInQueue', '-');
    }
    this.$el.append(this.template({ Stats: this.model.toJSON(), Prior: this.model.get('PriorDayStats') }));

    var self = this;
    this.graphView.model.fetch({

        success: function () {
            self.graphView.render(this.model.get("TotalCalls"), this.model.get("CallsAbandoned"));
        }
    });  
 this.tickerTapeText();
    $(window).trigger('resize');
```

However, when I run the application, I receive the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at success
```

Can someone help me diagnose what about my success function needs changed so that 'get' is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's `function` binds its own `this` which is different from the `this` of the context it's created in. In ES6, [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) were introduced as an alternative to a function that doesn't bind its own `this` (among others, see the MDN web docs).

You already worked around that by declaring a variable `self` and assigning `this` to it and used it for the `self.graphView.render` call. However, in the parameters, you still used `this` instead of `self`. Use `self` there, too, or even better use arrow functions if your environment implements them. [Current browsers should already support them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: So obvious! Thanks!

Comment: I received the same error for the following code:         _.each(this.model, function (client) {
            this.createGraphData(client.get("TotalCalls"),client.get("CallsAbandoned"));
        }); Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that's the same case (see `this.createGraphData`). `this` inside of a `function` will be a different `this`. Capture the outer `this` again with a `self`-variable or use arrow functions.

Comment: I have this, which isn't working:         var self = this;
        _.each(self.model, function (client) {
            self.createGraphData(client.get(totalCalls), client.get(callsAbandoned));

Comment: would you be willing to code out your potential solution?

Comment: What's the concrete error message for your sample? I believe there must be something wrong in `totalCalls` and/or `callsAbandoned` since your sample seems to be ok if the closing `});` was be there.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Is there actual data in the `this.model`-array that contains a get-function for every element?

Comment: I managed to resolve the error by using a backbone each method instead of using underscore. Thanks for the help!